# Can I trigger both Conduct Energy and Bespell Strikes from the same spell?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-2e, action-economy

[Bespell Strikes](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=5028&NoRedirect=1) adds 1d6 damage to a Strike after casting a Spell:

> **Requirements** Your last action or spell this turn had the acid, cold, electricity, fire, or sonic trait.

Conduct Energy adds 1 damage per weapon die after any activity or Spell:

> **Requirements** Your most recent action was to cast a non-cantrip spell

[Tempest Touch](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=763) satisfies both requirements, can I trigger both?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### No

Your "most recent/last action" is changed once you use either ability. You either cast *tempest touch* then used Bespell Strikes and no longer qualify for using Conduct Energy, or you cast *tempest touch* and used Conduct Energy and no longer qualify for Bespell Strikes.

Even Free Actions and Reactions are types of [Actions](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx) that can be your previous (or next) Action. This is the same reason you [cannot stack Spellshape](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=513) (formerly Metamagic) effects.